# $scope condicional no angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Olá!

Tenho estes radio buttons:

```
  <div class="row" ng-controller="GetDados">
            <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-5">
                <label class="radio-inline">
                  <input type="radio" name="optradio" ng-bind="pizza">Pizza
                </label>
                <label class="radio-inline">
                  <input type="radio" name="optradio" ng-bind="barras">Barras
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
```

essa é a ideia..

edit:

O que preciso é que quando escolher um radio button o angular execute uma ação, como exibir um gráfico através do $scope

edit:

Tentei isto, deu certo:

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="GetDados">
            <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-5">
                <label class="radio-inline">
                  <input type="radio" name="optradio" ng-click="pizza()" >Pizza
                </label>
                <label class="radio-inline">
                  <input type="radio" name="optradio" value="barra()" >Barras
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>



app.controller('GetDados', function($scope, $http){

    $http.get('http://localhost/api/v1/index.php/dados').
        success(function(data){
        $scope.dados = data;
    });    

    $scope.pizza = function() {
        console.log("oi");
    } 
});
```

Comment: Qual erro mostra no console? Formate sua pergunta, tem uma parte do código que saiu errado

Comment: Pergunta editada

Comment: Por que você não usa o ng-Click e coloca sua função para ser executada?

Comment: foi o que tentei...

Comment: "Tentei isto, deu certo:". Então ta bom. Porque está perguntando?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar uma só função no ng-click e verificar qual radio foi clicado através do $scope desta forma:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-5">
            <label class="radio-inline">
              <input type="radio" name="optradio" ng-model="escolha" value="pizza" ng-click="getInfo()">Pizza
            </label>
            <label class="radio-inline">
              <input type="radio" name="optradio" ng-model="escolha" value="barras" ng-click="getInfo()">Barras
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

no controller ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
app.controller('GetDados', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.getInfo = function(){
        $http.get('http://localhost/api/v1/index.php/dado').then(function(data){
            console.log(data);
            if($scope.escolha == "pizza"){
                console.log($scope.escolha);
            }
            else{
                console.log($scope.escolha);
            }               
        }, function(err){
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
} );
```